# iOS Test flight error due to code signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to submit a build to test flight but I am keep on getting this error saying my app is not signed.  However, I have added the right team 
and signing certificate thus I have no idea why I am getting such an error.

I did some googleing, looking up on stackoverflow and flip around some settings, however, I am still not able to get the desired result. :(

Any help would be appreciated!!

[image][image][image]

Comment: unsuported architectures [x86_64 and i386], must use [arm64, armv7, armv7s] instead

Comment: You have code signed your app with a development certificate. You're supposed to use a distribution certificate while using the app.

Comment: @KrishnaCA Thank you for your answer, and I think you are correct.  Hmmm how do I set one up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, You are getting this error because you've code signed your app with development certificate. You're supposed to use a distribution certificate for releasing the test flight.

For creating a distribution certificate, I suggest you the follow the steps listed [here](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios)

Comment: Distribution certificate was 1/2 of the problem, I also had to remove any .sh files within the 3rd party framework that I have, thanks again @KrishnaCA